# iOS9 iPad cannot import image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm developing a camera app which works perfect on iPhone but it has a trouble on iPad. I cannot see any photo from iPad simulator album and cannot import any image.

```
- (void)onPhoto{

    imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

    UIImage *importImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    NSLog(@"importImage is %f, %f",importImage.size.width, importImage.size.height);
}
```

I got nothing after imagePicker dismiss and the width and height are 0.0. If I set imagePicker edit option as

```
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
```

It will work. But I don't need the option. So anyone knows how to fix the problem on Xcode 7. Thanks.

Comment: do you see blank images on camera picker ?

Comment: This problem looks like to appear only on simulator but not on real device. This must be a bug.

Comment: Yes, I see many empty frames on iPad simulator and click it to get nothing after imagePicker dismiss. Is it really only on iPad simulator but works perfect on iPad device?

Comment: yes, it works perfect on device. I too faced this issue on simulator. I hope they fix it soon!!